# Make Chart Legend represent two colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, legend

I created a column chart in my application which look like this:

[image: Column chart with positive and negative colors]

As you can see the positive values are green and the negative values are red. I need to represent this in the legend. I just don't know how.

What I already tried:

I added `CustomItems` to the `Legend`. Here is the code:

```
Legend currentLegend = chart.Legends.FindByName(chart.Series[series].Legend);
if (currentLegend != null)
{
    currentLegend.LegendStyle   = LegendStyle.Table;
    LegendItem li               = new LegendItem();
    li.Name                     = series;
    li.Color                    = Color.Red;
    li.BorderColor              = Color.Transparent;
    currentLegend.CustomItems.Add(li);
}
```

This results in the following representation:

[image: Column chart with legend representing positive and negative color]

I could live with that. But as soon as I add further series to the chart the order of the elements gets destroyed. Here is an example:

[image]

I would like to have one of the two options:

1. keep the positive and negative color together
2. or an even better solution could be to have just one tile in the legend which is double colored. Something like this:

[image]

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Note however that you can't really modify the original `Legend`. So for a perfect result you would need to create a new custom `Legend` instead.

See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791944/how-to-add-data-table-with-legend-keys-to-a-ms-chart-in-c/35795254?s=2|1.8764#35795254) that does that; note especially the positioning..!

But maybe you can get away a little easier; see below!

The first rule to understand is that added `LegendItems` always **go to the end** of the list. So you can't keep them together, unless your added `Series` are at the **start. You can** do that by using `Series.Insert(..)` but using those two-color rectangles is much nicer, imo..

To show the graphics you want, simply create them as bitmaps, either on disk or on the fly and store them in the `Images` collection of the chart:

```
Legend L = chart1.Legends[0];
Series S = chart1.Series[0];

// either load an image from disk (or resources)
Image img = Image.FromFile(someImage);

// or create it on the fly:
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(32, 14);
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    G.Clear(Color.Red);
    G.FillPolygon(Brushes.LimeGreen, new Point[] { new Point(0,0), 
        new Point(32,0), new Point(0,14)});
}
```

Now add it to the chart's `NamedImage` collection:

```
chart1.Images.Add(new NamedImage("dia", bmp));
```

Now you can create as many `LegendItems` as you need:

```
LegendItem newItem = new LegendItem();
newItem.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Rectangle;
newItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Image, "dia", ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft);
newItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, S.Name, ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft);
```

And add them to the `Legend`:

```
L.CustomItems.Add(newItem);
```

Unfortunately you can't delete the original item.

What you can do, besides creating a new `Legend` from scratch, is this:

Clear the text like this:

```
S.LegendText = " "; // blank, not empty!
```

As you have set the `Colors` of **all** the `DataPoints` anyway, you can also get rid of the blue rectangle:

```
S.Color = Color.Transparent;
```

This will also  make all points without colors transparent, so make sure to color them all!

Note that some **space** in the Legend it still taken!

Here is the result, with a few colored points and your line series added:

[image]