# Combine BarChart and PointChart

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart, series

i got a Little "Problem", i want to create a Chart looking like this:

[image]

So basically 
Series 1 = Normal bar Chart. Color green if it Ends before the "time max" (series2)   Series 2 = just a DataPoint / Marker on top of series 1 items.

I am struggling with this though...

my Code:

```
        chart_TimeChart.Series.Clear();
        string series_timeneeded = "Time Needed";
        chart_TimeChart.Series.Add(series_timeneeded);
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded]["PixelPointWidth"] = "5";
        chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.Size = 10;
        chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle =    ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
        chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded].BorderWidth = 2;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar; 
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded].YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
        chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxNumber; i++) 
                {
                    chart_TimeChart.Series[series_timeneeded].Points.AddXY("item"+ " " + (i + 1).ToString(), DateTime.Now.Add(Timespans[i]));
                }

        chart_TimeChart.Series.Add(series_FinishTime);
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].BorderWidth = 0;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].MarkerSize = 15;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].MarkerColor = Color.Black;

        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].YValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxNumber; i++) 
                {
                    DateTime YPosition = GetFinishTime(i);

                    chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime].Points.AddXY("item"+ " " +(i+1).ToString(), YPosition);
                }
```

but this only Displays the 2nd series on top of the first one but the first one isnt visible anymore. The Maker of series 2 isnt shown but instead the bar is (eventhough i made borderwidth to 0). In my opinion/thinking i just have to make the "bar" of series 2 invisible and just Show the marker Points for series 2.

Any ideas?

---

**Update:**

```
string seriesname = Name+ i.ToString();
                    chart_TimeChart.Series.Add(seriesname);
                    chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].SetCustomProperty("DrawSideBySide", "false");
                    chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                    chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar; //Y and X are exchanged
                    chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                    chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
                    chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

                    DateTime TimeNeeded = DateTime.Now.Add(List_AllLiniengroupsTimespans[k][i]); 
                    DateTime TimeMax = GetFinishTime(k, i); 
                    TimeSpan TimeDifference = TimeNeeded - TimeMax;

                    if (TimeNeeded > TimeMax) //All good
                    {
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY(seriesname, TimeNeeded); //Time till finish
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].Color = Color.Blue; 
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY(seriesname, TimeNeeded.Add(TimeDifference)); //time left
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[1].Color = Color.Red;
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[1].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                    }
                    else if (TimeMax > TimeNeeded) //wont make it in time
                    {
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY(seriesname, TimeNeeded); //time till still okay
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].Color = Color.Blue; 
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY(seriesname, TimeNeeded.Add(TimeDifference)); //Time that is too much
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[1].Color = Color.Green; 
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[1].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                    }
                    else if (TimeMax == TimeNeeded) //fits exactly
                    {
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY(seriesname, TimeNeeded); 
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].Color = Color.DarkOrange; 
                        chart_TimeChart.Series[seriesname].Points[0].SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", seriesname);

                    }
```

the Code will be displayed as:

[image]

but i want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: btw. i tried "  chart_TimeChart.Series[series_FinishTime]["PixelPointWidth"] = "0"; but apparently this does not work =/ since i can´t set the width to Zero.

Comment: Do have a look at the updated answer. I misread you question at first, sorry!

Comment: You still have the charttype as stackedbars. I don't think it actually is what you want. And you still add x-values as strings. You need numbers, though. You need to think of a scheme to use simple numbers to group the points to their respective slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**!! See the update below !!**

---

If you really want to create a StackedBar chart, your chart has **two** issues:

- If you want to stack datapoints they **need** to have meaningful x-values; without them how can it know what to stack on each other?

You add strings, which look fine but simply don't work. That is because the `DataPoint.XValue` field is `double` and when you add `string` into it it is set to  `0` !! Your string is copied to the `Label` but otherwise lost.

So you **need** to come up with a suitable **numeric** value you use for the x-values..

- And you also need to **group** the series you want to stack. For this there is a special property called `StackedGroupName` which serves to group those series that shall be stacked.

Here is how you can use it:

```
yourSeries1.SetCustomProperty("StackedGroupName", "Group1");
```

For a full example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853610/how-to-add-background-color-to-columns-in-chart/49855033?s=1|31.3087#49855033) !

It also shows one way of setting the Labels with string values of your choice..

This is the way to go for real `StackedBar` charts. Your workaround may or may not work. You could try to make the colors transparent or equal to the chart's backcolor; but it won't be more than a hack, imo.

---

**Update**

I guess I have misread the question. From what I see you do not really want to create a stacked chart.

Instead you struggle with these issues:

- displaying bars at the same y-spot
- making some bars invisible
- displaying a vertical line as a marker

Let's tackle each:

- Some column types including all `Bars`, `Columns` and then some have a little known **special property** called [`DrawSideBySide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456710.aspx).

By default is is set to `Auto`, which will work like `True`. This is usually fine as we don't want bars to sit upon each other, effectively hiding all or part of the overlaid points.

But here we do want them to share the same y-position, so we need to set the property to `false` for at least one `Series`; the others (on `Auto`) will follow..:

You can do it either like this:

```
aSeries["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
```

or like this:

```
aSeries.SetCustomProperty("DrawSideBySide", "false");
```

---

- Next we **hide** the overlaid `Series`; this is simple:

---

```
aSeries.Color = Color.Transparent;
```

- The last issue is displaying a line marker. There is no such [`MarkerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx), so we need to use a custom style. For this we need to create a suitable bitmap and add it as a [`NamedImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.namedimage(v=vs.110).aspx) to the chart's `Images` collection.

This sounds more complicated than it is; however the `MarkerImage` will not be scaled, so we need to created suitable sizes whenever we resize the Chart or add/remove points. I will ignore this complication for now..

```
int pointCount = 10;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2, chart.ClientSize.Height / pointCount - 5);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) g.Clear(Color.Black);
NamedImage marker = new NamedImage("marker", bmp);
chart.Images.Clear();  // quick & dirty
chart.Images.Add(marker);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

A few notes:

- I would recommend to use variables for all chart elements you refer to repeatedly instead of using indexed references all the time. Less code, easier to read, a lot easier to maintain, and probably better performance.
- Since your code called for the visible datapoints to be either red or green the `Legend` will not show a good representation. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614148/make-chart-legend-represent-two-colors/36619240?s=1|66.5576#36619240) for an example of drawing a multi-colored legend item..
- I used the chart height; this is not really recommended as there may be `Titles` or `Legends` or even more `ChartAreas`; instead you should use the height of the `ChartArea`, or even more precise, the height of the `InnerPlotPosition`. You would need to convert those from percentages to pixels. Not too hard, see below or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262#36497262)
  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221672/constrain-aspect-ratio-in-windowsforms-datavisualization-chart/36248343?s=4|31.4713#36248343) for more examples!
- The markers should be adapted from the `Resize` and probably from the `AxisViewChanged` events. Putting it in a nice function to call (e.g. `void setMarkerImage(Chart chart, Series s, string name, int width, Color c)`) is always a good idea.
- If you need to adapt the size of the marker image repeatedly, you may want to write better code for clearing the old one; this should include disposing of the `Bitmap` that was used before..

Here is an example:

```
var oldni = chart.Images.FindByName("marker");
if (oldni != null)
{
    oldni.Image.Dispose();
    chart.Images.Remove(oldni);
    oldni.Dispose();
}
```

- In some situations one needs to nudge the Chart to update some of its properties; `RecalculateAxesScale` is one such nudge.

Example for calculating a suitable marker height:

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
ca.RecalculateAxesScale();
float cah = ca.Position.Height;
float iph = ca.InnerPlotPosition.Height;
float h = chart3.ClientSize.Height * cah / 100f * iph / 100f;
int mh = (int)(h / s.Points.Count);
```

- Final note: The original answer stressed the importance of using **meaningful x-values**. Strings are useless! This was important for stacking bars; but it is **equally important** now, when we want bars to sit at the same vertical positions! Adding the x-values as strings is again resulting in nonsense..

(Since we have `Bars` the x-values go along the vertical axis and vice versa..)

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed answer! I tried a lot and i get what you mean. I updated my original post. I still have the Problem with the strings on my "x-Axis" eventhough i now add only the Points that should be stacked to the same series and create multiple series , one forfor each item. Why is that the case? and how do i solve this?
THANK YOU SO MUCH for the effort! it really helps!

Comment: Is `seriesname` a number? That would help. Not sure, the code is incomplete at the start; maybe `i` is the series index? If so you could maybe use it as x-value [DrawSideBySide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456710.aspx) is only valid for some types.

Comment: Ah i got it now, the Problem is still with the strings! Damn me, let me try it with double instead =)

Comment: Yes, and make all series Bars, not StackedBars so DrawSideBSide can make them overlay..

Comment: With double it works fine, just the order is turned (Point 0 is placed behind Point 1) but this is no Problem. I think i understood and got it now! Thank you! I will answer again in some minutes =)

Comment: I have a Little Problem with the full Code , i set the Y.LabelStyle to "HH:mm:ss"  and then mark the Points. But the Diagramm of Course always starts at the time of "00:00:00" is there any way to let it start at a specific time? for example current date? I tried  chart_TimeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);   but i can´t convert TimeSpan to Double. And the requested DataType by the Debugger is double (eventhough i have "HH:mm:ss") i know ist a bit of Topic but any idea?

Comment: Not sure of what you want but there are functions to convert between DateTime and Double: `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
double dd = dt.ToOADate();
DateTime ddt = DateTime.FromOADate(dd);` But TimeSpan is only a relative thing and can't be converted to an absolute datetetime.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed Response. Everything is working just fine! And i played a bit with what you said, you were just right! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! Have a nice day!