# How to find the crossing of axis in pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am implementing two crosshair cursors using labels for winforms chart after following tutorials on youtube. I am using the cursors to find the values on my graph but I need to find the max and minimum positions of the x-yaxis in order to prevent overrange exception

My approach was to find the crossing of the axis inorder to find the minimum and maximum as following:

Minimum: crossing of primary x- and yaxis
Max: crossing of primary x- and yaxis + width and height.

Here is a picture of the point I am trying to find the pixel value for

[Points I am trying to find the pixel values for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUMod.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x0 = Convert.ToInt32(chart1.Width * decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32(chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X),100) + Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32(chart1.Width*chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width *chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width*chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.X),1000000)))-10;
 x1 = Convert.ToInt32(x0 + Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32(chart1.Width * chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width * chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Width),10000)))+10;
y0 = Convert.ToInt32(chart1.Height*decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32( chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y),100)+ Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32(chart1.Height*chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height * chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height * chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Y),1000000)))-15;
y1 = Convert.ToInt32(y0 + chart1.Height *decimal.Divide(Convert.ToInt32(chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height * chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Height),10000))+25;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Axis functions to convert between the chart's 3 coordinate systems (pixels, values and positions).

The values to look for are probably the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

var x0 = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Minimum);
var y0 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Minimum);
var x1 = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Maximum);
var y1 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Maximum);
```

You may want to study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991598/how-does-one-set-an-image-as-or-along-a-chart-axis/49996252?r=SearchResults&s=1|53.9818#49996252) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221672/constrain-aspect-ratio-in-windowsforms-datavisualization-chart/36248343?r=SearchResults&s=2|48.5687#36248343) for more on finding pixel positions in a chart..

Note that the actual crossing can be shifted by setting the `Axis.Crossing` values!

Comment: The code throws the following error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for your help though!