# C#: How to show point value in below of chart?

Tags: c#, charts

I want to show my point(X axis and Y axis) value below my chart as a table format. and every point located just below the point of chart.

This is my actual output screen.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY8dn.png)

This is my expected output screen.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqy1u.png)

My class Code is below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Series b in chart1.Series)
        {
            b.Label = "#VALY{#,##0}";
        }

        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Blue;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(j+1, j*2);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can either use a more suitable control, like a DataGridView for this part or you can study [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791944/how-to-add-data-table-with-legend-keys-to-a-ms-chart-in-c/35795254?s=3|1.8766#35795254), which shows an example of creating a custom legend below the chart. This could easily be modified to show the values..