# Adding legend to winforms point chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am building a winform point chart using C# where the data comes from a datatable.  I've created the points like this:

```
chart1.Series.Add("series1");
chart1.Series["series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
chart1.Series["series1"].YValueMembers = "VALUE";
chart1.Series["series1"].XValueMember = "DATE";
chart1.DataSource = dt;
```

I'd like to be able make a legend of the points on the chart using different colors/symbols based on a third column in the datatable dt called product.  I've tried a number of things to get this done but nothing is working.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456711.aspx

Comment: Is this a Pie chart? Other types will by default show one legendItem per series. If you want something different, like legenditems for each point you wil need to create a new legend along with all the items in code. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791944/how-to-add-data-table-with-legend-keys-to-a-ms-chart-in-c/35795254#35795254) of creating a custom legend.  - You will not be able to use databinding on a legend btw.  - Please elaborate more on what you want..!

Comment: I realized my problem this morning - I'll update/answer my own question for future reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of my problem was first understanding how to construct charts in the first place.  I realized I needed to create a series for each unique product in my datatable and add those to the chart.  I first made a list of unique products in the datatable:

```
        List<string> products = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (!products.Contains(row["product"].ToString()))
            {
                products.Add(row["product"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Then

```
       foreach (string product in products)
        {
            string seriesName = product;
            chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
            DataTable dtprod = new DataTable();
            dtprod = dt.Select("product= '" + product + "'").CopyToDataTable();
            chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            chart1.Series[seriesName].YValueMembers = "VALUE";
            chart1.Series[seriesName].XValueMember = "DATE";
            chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.DataBindXY(dtprod.Rows,"DATE", dtprod.Rows, "VALUE");
            chart1.Series[seriesName].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            chart1.Series[seriesName].MarkerSize = 10;
        }
```

This produced a point chart with a unique marker for each product.  Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code I got from [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456711.aspx)

```
// Create a new legend called "Legend2".
chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend2"));

// Set Docking of the Legend chart to the Default Chart Area.
chart1.Legends["Legend2"].DockToChartArea = "Default"; 

// Assign the legend to Series1.
chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Legend2";
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
```